# Trouble with parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql, db2, odbc, parameterized-query

I'm having trouble with a parameterized query in ODBC that usually works when I'm working with SQLClient objects.

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN = @MYPARAM";
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@MYPARAM",myValue));

        using (OdbcDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader)
        {
            //do stuff
        } 
    }
}
```

The message I get is

> ERROR [42S22] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0206N  "@MYPARAM" is not
>   valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

But if I'm using the SQLClient namespace I can replace `Odbc` with `Sql` everywhere above and it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Solved the issue by removing comments from SQL (e.g. `-- some comment`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`OdbcParameter.ParameterName Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.parametername%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Instead of named parameters, the ODBC .NET Provider uses positional
>   parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) in the syntax of
>   the command text.** Parameter objects in the OdbcParameterCollection and
>   the actual parameters accepted by the stored procedure or
>   parameterized SQL statement correspond to each other based on the
>   order in which the OdbcParameter objects are inserted into the
>   collection instead of by parameter name.

That's why you should use your parameters as;

```
comm.CommandText = @"SELECT MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
                     WHERE MYCOLUMN = ?";
comm.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@MYPARAM",myValue));
```

Actually, it doesn't matter what you write parameter name in [`OdbcParameter` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter.OdbcParameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) because the real important thing is **order** for `OdbcParameter` parameters.

That's why both bottom lines work for your `CommandText` because you have only one parameter `:-)`

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("user2320861",myValue));
comm.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("meaningless string",myValue));
```